# Manage library workflow with multiple categories

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-library

I thought I had posted this question yesterday however I can't find it. My apologies if it is a duplicate.

I have a library where the documents are categorized by their type ie: Admin, Finance, Support.

I have created one workflow for one category, to distribute a link to the document when it is uploaded. However by using this method, I have to create a workflow for each category.

I am hoping that there is a way to have one workflow which will look at the category and send the e-mail to the associated security group.

My first thought was to create a workflow with multiple If branches: If category = Finance send to Finance group, if category = Admin send to admin group so on.

Is there a better way to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to manage the workflows in your case.

1. If you have multiple content types (e.g.: Admin Doc, Finance Doc and etc...) then you can write a content type workflow and triggers on type fo document.
2. If you don`t have content type and managing through the list columns as Category then you can write a List workflow and manage notifications through the IF conditions. You are in a right direction if you fall under this case.